# How can I get web server information about a page I'm viewing (e.g. Apache or IIS, Windows or UNIX)?

Tags: browser, apache-http-server, webserver, iis

When I check pages for broken links using [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) it usefully lists information about the web server, OS and PHP version
 e.g.

```
Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8j PHP5.2.9
```

Is there a simple way to extract similar information from the browser when viewing a page e.g. by a Javascript snippet/bookmarklet?

**Update**
The server information is part of the HTTP response header which is not accessible to Javascript. So a Javascript/bookmarklet solution would not be directly possible (though it could do something like sending the page URL to a site like Arjan's below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Web Developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) for Firefox has among its many options a way to view page response headers. (Information | View Response Headers)

Comment: Aha! I already have the Web Dev toolbar installed but hadn't noticed that menu item. Thanks.

Comment: Always happy to help.

Comment: Good answer, but it won't show the operating system (unless the web server includes that), does it?

Comment: Probably. It might require some inference. superuser.com returns "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0" as one of the values. IIS 7 implies Windows Server 2008, does it not?

Comment: Well, there's more than one flavour of Windows ;-) And for some installations the response headers just return "Apache" (like for http://rubyforge.org) or "nginx" (like for http://gravatar.com). (But I guess the question asker doesn't really care about that; using the Developer Toolbar surely is an easy way to get some information. And neither the response headers nor Netcraft can figger out what http://twitter.com is using...)

Comment: The link for Web Developer Tools seems to be dead, is [this new one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) equivalent?

Answer (score 5):

`curl -I yoursite.com` is another simple way to at least see what kind of server it is as well as some other basic header information.

Comment: He asked "from the browser". `curl` is a command line utility.

Comment: I think this is still relevant information for anyone who views this thread and is looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The information you mention seems the same as Netcraft's "[What's that site running](https://sitereport.netcraft.com/)" provides. Still note that this information is not by definition The Truth; a web server can report anything it likes.

Also, it's just never [as complete](https://sitereport.netcraft.com/?url=http://stackoverflow.com)<sup>†</sup> as [the real story](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network).

<sup><sup>†</sup> I didn't know IIS could [run on Linux](https://uptime.netcraft.com/up/accuracy.html#os)? Ah, Jeff says some parts of SO are Linux, like the load balancer ([HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.org/)).</sup>

Comment: Re: stackoverflow.com. Strange, the header just reports 'Microsoft-IIS/7.0'. I wonder where Netcraft gets the OS from. Is this a virtual machine thing???

Comment: Ah, just seen your other link re. OS detection...

Answer (score 2):

**Or from Chrome Dev Tools**

`Network > All > Headers`

Refresh the page then click the site name at the top of the list in the 'Name' panel and look at the Response Headers:
[image]
Though for security, fewer and fewer sites include this information nowadays.